# How do I convert an HttpRequest into an HttpRequestBase object?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httprequest

My problem is the opposite of this:
 [How do I convert an HttpRequestBase into an HttpRequest object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452522/how-do-i-convert-an-httprequestbase-into-an-httprequest-object)

In my ASP.NET MVC application I have a method used by many controllers that receive an HttpRequestBase as argument.

Now I have to call that method from another method, that is not an action (it's an nhibernate interceptor). In this second method I could access HttpContext.Current.Request, that is a HttpRequest and I cannot cast it to HttpRequestBase (I thought it was possibile due to the naming ...).

Does someone know in what relationship are this classes and how can I solve my problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You'll want to wrap your `HttpRequest` in a `HttpRequestWrapper`:

```
var wrapper = new HttpRequestWrapper(httpRequest);
```

The `HttpRequestWrapper` inherits from `HttpRequestBase`.

Comment: might be helpful `new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request)`

Answer (score 31):

This is an another solution which does not require to create a new instance:

```
var httpRequestBase = myHttpRequest.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
```

Answer (score 2):

In my application I had calls coming from several different places that needed access to the HttpRequestBase. I created this set of extension methods to get and convert from several different Http types into a HttpRequestBase, then used HttpRequestBase as the base type for interface and class methods through the application when I needed access to the request.

```
public static class RequestExtensions
{
    public static HttpRequestBase GetHttpRequestBase(this HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Context is null.");
        }

        return httpContext.Request.ToHttpRequestBase();
    }

    public static HttpRequestBase GetHttpRequestBase(this HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage)
    {
        if (httpRequestMessage == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Request message is null.");
        }

        HttpContextWrapper context = null;
        if (httpRequestMessage.Properties.ContainsKey("MS_HttpContext"))
        {
            context = httpRequestMessage.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextWrapper;
        }
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Context is null.");
        }

        return context.Request;
    }

    public static HttpRequestBase GetHttpRequestBase(this HttpApplication httpApplication)
    {
        if (httpApplication == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Application is null.");
        }

        return httpApplication.Request.ToHttpRequestBase();
    }

    public static HttpRequestBase ToHttpRequestBase(this HttpRequest httpRequest)
    {
        if (httpRequest == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Request is null.");
        }

        return new HttpRequestWrapper(httpRequest);
    }
}
```

I came across several SO answers that helped me build these extensions:

- [How do I convert an HttpRequestBase into an HttpRequest object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15112174/579148)
- [Convert HttpRequestMessage to HttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17426823/579148)
- [Get the IP address of the remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9571292/579148)

Answer (score 0):

I find the following extension methods useful:

```
    public static HttpContextBase AsBase(this HttpContext context)
    {
        return new HttpContextWrapper(context);
    }

    public static HttpRequestBase AsBase(this HttpRequest context)
    {
        return new HttpRequestWrapper(context);
    }
```

Usage:

```
HttpContext.Current.AsBase()
HttpContext.Current.Request.AsBase()
```