# Convert HttpRequestMessage to HttpRequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httprequest

I'm converting ASP.NET web application to MVC Web Api project.
One of my methods expects `HttpRequest` class. However, Web Api controller holds only `HttpRequestMessage` (`this.Request`) object.
Do you know how I can convert `HttpRequestMessage` to `HttpRequest`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You probably don't need to convert from *HttpRequestMessage*. There is another way:

```
var context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
HttpRequestBase request = context.Request;
```

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request

Comment: This seems awfully like cheating to me but I'm forced to do it if I want to write functions that can be called from ASP.NET Web API controllers as well as ASP.NET MVC controllers. For the life of me I don't understand by web API couldn't just be built on top of MVC (so ApiController could be a subclass of a normal MVC Controller). Instead if you want to use MVC and API together you have to navigate between two parallel but incompatible worlds with the same concepts in each.

Comment: I've seen on the comments under [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565889/get-the-ip-address-of-the-remote-host#10998580) that you shouldn't use System.Web.HttpContext.Current in Web API projects - you can instead use `(HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]`

Answer (score -1):

Try to use/create a HttpRequestWrapper using your HttpRequestBase.

Comment: How do I get an 'HttpRequestBase'? should I create one myself? (i.e. create new object and copy 'HttpRequestMessage' parameters to it)

Comment: you can get HttpRequestBase using `((HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request`